# Laravel Eloquent date(now) compare two date not working

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this on Simple query

```
SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE DATE(NOW()) = DATE(updated_at)
```

and it shows result,

but when I try

```
$blog = Blog::whereDate('updated_at', '=', 'DATE(NOW())')->get();

$blog = Blog::where('DATE(NOW())','=', 'DATE(updated_at)')->get();

$blog = Blog::where(DB::RAW('DATE(NOW()) = DATE(updated_at)'))->get();
```

tried these three... still can't

Comment: Check your general log and see the actual query generated by Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in several ways:

```
$blog = Blog::whereDate('updated_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
$blog = Blog::whereDate('updated_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->get();
$blog = Blog::whereRaw('DATE(NOW()) = DATE(updated_at)')->get();
$blog = Blog::where(DB::RAW('DATE(NOW())'), '=', DB::RAW('DATE(updated_at)'))->get();
```

**P.S.**

Also take a look on this:

```
whereDay('updated_at', '=', date('d'));
whereMonth('updated_at', '=', date('m'));
whereYear('updated_at', '=', date('Y'));
```